# Android : Enlarge ImageView within RecyclerView with animation onClick Like in watsapp

Tags: android, animation, imageview, zooming, android-fullscreen

I have an android application where in a module i used a Recycler view in which each view containing a image view and text view for account name.Now when I click on the image view, it should enlarge the image with the account name at the top and two button for edit and delete at the bottom of the enlarged image and should be displayed at the center like in watsapp.Also when i click on the enlarged view it should displayed in full screen with header containing the back button and share button.How can i do these two things exactly like in watsapp.How can i do this? If someone know exactly the same technique that is used in watsapp please help me.

Comment: use this library https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: @AmitRanjan is this is the method used in watsapp??

Comment: You could show a popup dialog with a custom layout with the necessary views you want and just pass the data for each view from the item being clicked position. Within the pop-up dialog you can have another click listener that again shows a popup dialog with the fullscreen image and a toolbar. I'll post code when I'm in front of my computer again.

Comment: ok.i will wait for your post...

Comment: @SteveC. which one to use for popup dialog??is it DialogFragment??

Comment: @KJEjava48 Give me a few. I'm putting together the example code for you.

Comment: @KJEjava48 I apologize but I am having issues with Android Studio. I was basically creating a modified version of [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/09/custom-dialogfragmnet-example-in-android.html) tutorial to give you what you're looking for. I would use an ImageButton for the images and for the full screen image, set the OnClickListener in the dialog's imagebutton to open a new activity that shows the image fullscreen. As long as you set the parentActivity of that class in your manifest to the previous activity it'll show the back arrow. Let me know if you need more help.